# left right down up keyboard to move an object using JS

Tags: javascript

I want to make an image moving on the screen up down right and left.
it only moves up and down
I can't fix my code

here is what I was working on so far

```
frame.on ("keydown", function(e)  {
  zog(e.keyCode); // e is an event object
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    dir = -1;
  } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
    dir = 1;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37){ //left
    dir = 0;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39){ //right
    dir = 0;
  }
});
frame.on ("keyup", function()  {
  dir = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will update the box position every time you press the arrow buttons on your keyboard. Keep in mind up/down will make the page scroll up/down. But that's a diff problem to solve ;)

```js
(function($){$(function(){
var box = $('.box');
  
  $('body').on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      box.css('top', box.offset().top - 1);
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
      box.css('top', box.offset().top + 1);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37){ //left
      box.css('left', box.offset().left - 1);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39){ //right
      box.css('left', box.offset().left + 1);
    }
  });
  
})})(jQuery);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
```